# How to add dependency to godep.json?

Tags: go

I'm having hard time to add a dependency to the `Godeps.json` file. I think I've messed up the `GOPATH`. I tried various suggestions on the warnings but none of them worked for me. 
My GOPATH is `/Users/sarath/project`. 
`which go` is `/usr/local/bin/go`.  If I try to do `godep save ./...`, it is giving me the following warning:

```
godep: [WARNING]: godep should only be used inside a valid go package directory and
godep: [WARNING]: may not function correctly. You are probably outside of your $GOPATH.
godep: [WARNING]:   Current Directory: /Users/sarath/project
godep: [WARNING]:   $GOPATH: /Users/sarath/project
godep: Unable to find SrcRoot for package .
```

I have my `pkg` inside the `/Users/sarath/project`.

Comment: see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That definitely won't work. GOPATH isn't just the path of some project; it's the root of a directory, which contains `bin`, `pkg`, and `src` directories; the `src` directory contains package-named directories for projects. So you should be running `godep` from your project directory, which (given your current GOPATH) should be `/Users/sarath/project/src/<repopath>` - e.g. `/Users/sarath/project/src/github.com/sarath/myproject`.